inference variable has incompatible equality constraints
A class ServerServiceDefinition with generic types defined here. I'm trying to take an existing instance of this class, modify some properties and reconstruct another instance of  a ServerServiceDefinition by calling the addMethod declared as
public <ReqT, RespT> Builder addMethod(
        MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> handler)

Below is my code
public ServerServiceDefinition bindService() {
    ServerServiceDefinition serverServiceDefinitionV1 = ProtoReflectionServiceV1.newInstance()
        .bindService();
    MethodDescriptor<?, ?> methodDescriptorV1 = serverServiceDefinitionV1.getServiceDescriptor()
        .getMethods().iterator().next(); // Because there is only 1 method in the service.
    MethodDescriptor<?, ?> methodDescriptorV1Alpha = methodDescriptorV1.toBuilder()
        .setFullMethodName(generateFullMethodName(SERVICE_NAME, METHOD_NAME))
        .setSchemaDescriptor(
            new ServerReflectionMethodDescriptorSupplier(METHOD_NAME))
        .build();
    ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptorV1Alpha = ServiceDescriptor.newBuilder(SERVICE_NAME)
        .setSchemaDescriptor(new ServerReflectionFileDescriptorSupplier())
        .addMethod(methodDescriptorV1Alpha)
        .build();
    return ServerServiceDefinition.builder(serviceDescriptorV1Alpha)
        .addMethod(methodDescriptorV1Alpha,
            serverServiceDefinitionV1.getMethod(
                generateFullMethodName(ServerReflectionGrpc.SERVICE_NAME, METHOD_NAME))
                    .getServerCallHandler())
        .build();
  }

which fails to compile on the addMethod call arguments:
error: no suitable method found for addMethod(MethodDescriptor<CAP#1,CAP#2>,ServerCallHandler<CAP#3,CAP#4>)
        .addMethod(methodDescriptorV1Alpha,
        ^
    method Builder.<ReqT#1,RespT#1>addMethod(MethodDescriptor<ReqT#1,RespT#1>,ServerCallHandler<ReqT#1,RespT#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable ReqT#1 has incompatible equality constraints CAP#5,CAP#1)
where ReqT#1,RespT#1 are type-variables:
    ReqT#1 extends Object declared in method <ReqT#1,RespT#1>addMethod(MethodDescriptor<ReqT#1,RespT#1>,ServerCallHandler<ReqT#1,RespT#1>)
    RespT#1 extends Object declared in method <ReqT#1,RespT#1>addMethod(MethodDescriptor<ReqT#1,RespT#1>,ServerCallHandler<ReqT#1,RespT#1>)
where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3,CAP#4,CAP#5 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#3 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#4 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#5 extends Object from capture of ?      

How to resolve this?

Please use code format for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log entries, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Reformatting done.

The trick is to avoid using ? in the generics from the start, by introducing template variables, so that the compiler knows that different objects with generics are composed of the same (set of) template variables.
private <ReqT, RespT> ServerServiceDefinition createServerServiceDefinition() {
    ServerServiceDefinition serverServiceDefinitionV1 = ProtoReflectionServiceV1.newInstance()
        .bindService();
    MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptorV1 = (MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT>) serverServiceDefinitionV1.getServiceDescriptor()
        .getMethods().iterator().next();
    MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptorV1Alpha = methodDescriptorV1.toBuilder()
        .setFullMethodName(generateFullMethodName(SERVICE_NAME, METHOD_NAME))
        .setSchemaDescriptor(
            new ServerReflectionMethodDescriptorSupplier(METHOD_NAME))
        .build();
    ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptorV1Alpha = ServiceDescriptor.newBuilder(SERVICE_NAME)
        .setSchemaDescriptor(new ServerReflectionFileDescriptorSupplier())
        .addMethod(methodDescriptorV1Alpha)
        .build();
    return ServerServiceDefinition.builder(serviceDescriptorV1Alpha)
        .addMethod(methodDescriptorV1Alpha, createServerCallHandler(serverServiceDefinitionV1))
        .build();
  }

